# How to set umask for php5-fpm in ubuntu 13.10

Tags: php-fpm, umask

I am currently running `nginx` with `php5-fpm` on my local development ubuntu 13.10 system with `3.12.0` linux kernel.

Before update, to set umask to 0002 for php5-fpm I edited `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm` file and added `--umask` arg to `start-stop-daemon` line.

After update it is ignored.

All points that now I run `upstart` instead of bare old `system V` scripts.

I tried to add `umask 0002` to `/etc/init/php5-fpm.conf` but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long boring google search the answer is:

```
umask 0002
```

In the very start of `/etc/init.d/php5-fpm`

I checked it with `gdb` to be really sure(gdb --pid=PID of php5-fpm):

```
(gdb) call umask(0)
$1 = 2
(gdb) call umask(2)
$2 = 0
```

Comment: The init script should not be modified (it could be overwritten by a package update), putting it in `/etc/default/php5-fpm` is probably safer (this file is sourced near the beginning of the init script).

Comment: I have since then moved to systemd which just allows UMask=0002 in the unit files, and overriding system files with the custom unit files. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/systemd.exec.5.html