# Proper Way of Setting Umask For php-fpm on Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, debian, php-fpm, umask

I'd like to set umask to 002 for the php-fpm process. I'm reading [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/558963/how-to-set-umask-for-php5-fpm-in-ubuntu-13-10) and [here](http://www.fabianfier.de/blog1.php/set-creation-umask-for-php) that on Ubuntu/Debian it is supposed to be done by modifying the init script.

I'm having doubts however that this is the proper way. Just thinking about the case php5-fpm gets updated and an update modifies the init script.

I also read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1315147/1016746) that for CentOS/Redhat you can set it via `/etc/sysconfig/`.

So my question is whether there is a proper way on Debian/Ubuntu to set the umask without modifying the init script? In case there is not, is it OK to modify the init script directly?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but for anyone else who comes along modifying www.conf and adding env[UMASK] = 0002 solved the problem. Note the three 000 before the 2, no two as in the respondent's answer above.

Comment: Also, don't forget to remove or chown any files that were created under the old username. I had a cache directory that needed to be removed before the new settings could take affect.

Comment: What is the difference between 002 and 0002? According to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/13269502/1016746 there is none.

Answer (score 2):

You can always change Umask for whole Systemd service by adding config file `/etc/systemd/system/my-service-name-whatever.d/umask.conf` with content like:

```
[Service]
UMask=0002
```

Comment: In a modern system with systemd, this is the poper way to give the umask setting. E.g. for a nginx server using php-fpm.service, you can set this in any file in `/etc/systemd/system/php-fpm.service.d/` . Be carful to name it case sensitive with `UMask=0002`. Reference: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.exec.html#UMask=

Answer (score 1):

[Corresponding to the debian maintainer](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=703121#10) you can use the */etc/apache2/envvars* for apache, so maybe there is a corresponding file for phpfpm? Also systemd has a umask setting in unit files, however I don't think it is honored if the service does not have a native systemd unit file.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think what you're writing is correct and partially applies to php-fpm as well. Having a similar approach you can set envvars in `/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` by adding lines like `env[TMP] = /tmp`. But the apache *envvars* file it's more like a script, and the php-fpm pool config is really just a config file. I also tried adding `env[UMASK] = 002`, obviously without any effect :)